# FBA authorization in custom WCF SharePoint

Tags: wcf, sharepoint

I have soap WCF SharePoint:

     `[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{`

```
[OperationContract]
string Test();
```

}

`[BasicHttpBindingServiceMetadataExchangeEndpoint]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
public class Service : IService
{`

```
public string Test()
{
    WindowsIdentity identity = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity;

    ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(identity);

    return SPContext.Current.Web.Title;
}
 }
```

This service mapped on ISAPI.On SharePoint use FBA. And  How connect to WCF that impersonate/authenticate FBA user?

Answer (score 0):

When enable windows and fba authentication order to use windows authentciation need add header "X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED" with value "f": I use restsharp:

```
 request.AddHeader("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f")
```